# Google Sheet API Delete Rows containing a value

Tags: google-sheets-api

So,

I have a spreadsheet that I update from a node script.

But I don't find any documentation on how to:

- Find all the rows that have a value (example: '2019-09-06') in column A
- Delete these matching rows

Thanks a lot !

The actual script is pretty basic for now

```js
async function appendData(spreadsheetId, sheets, rows) {
    return await sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
        valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
        spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
        range: 'API',
        requestBody: {
            values: rows,
        },
    });
}

const auth = await getAuth();
const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
const result = await appendData('xxSHEET_IDxx', sheets, [].concat(...rows));
```

Comment: I think that there are several methods for achieving your goal. So can I ask you about your situation? 1. Do you want to find the value from all sheets in several Spreadsheets? Or Do you want to find the value from one sheet in several Spreadsheets? Or do you want to find the value from all sheets in one Spreadsheet? Or do you want to find the value from one sheet in one Spreadsheet? 2. About `Delete these matching rows`, you want to delete rows or delete values from the cells? 3. Can you provide your current script of `a node script`?

Comment: What I want to achieve is: I have a node script that pull a web service to retrieve stats from a back end and append new rows (date, product, qty) to a spreadsheet (single sheet). But sometimes I have to rerun the script on existing dates in that sheet, meaning I need to delete existing rows containing these date (doesn't matter the row order) before appending the updated ones, to avoid duplicates

Comment: What I've found so far is pulling the all entire sheet (heavy) filter rows in js and delete ranges afterward :[

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your 1st replying, in your situation, you want to delete the rows from one sheet in one Spreadsheet by searching a value from the column "A". You want to achieve this using googleapis with Node.js. I could understand like this. Is my understanding correct? From your 2nd replying, I cannot understand about `pulling the all entire sheet (heavy) filter rows`. Can you explain about this? In my proposal, after the values from the column "A" are retrieved, the rows are deleted by searching the value. In this case, 2 API calls are used. How about this?

Answer (score 1):

Something that works

```
async function removeMatchingRows(spreadsheetId, sheets, date) {
    const result = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
        range: 'API!A:A',
    });

    let ranges = [];
    var current = {
        dimension: "ROWS",
        startIndex: 0,
        endIndex: 0
    };
    for(var i = 0; i < result.data.values.length; i++) {
        if (result.data.values[i][0] == date) {
            if (current.endIndex === i - 1 || current.startIndex === 0) {
                if (current.startIndex === 0) {
                    current.startIndex = i;
                }
                current.endIndex = i + 1;
            } else {
                ranges.push(current);
                current = {
                    dimension: "ROWS",
                    startIndex: i,
                    endIndex: i + 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (current.startIndex !== 0) {
        ranges.push(current);
    }
    let requests = ranges.map(range => {
        return {
            deleteDimension: {
                range: range
            }
        }
    }).reverse();

    await sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
        spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
        requestBody: {
            requests: requests
        }
    });
}
```